# Using globe view in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-engine

I'm working on a tool to visualize climate data in Google Earth Engine, and it'd be very nice if I could view the Earth as a 3D globe (i.e., from "space", rotate it, etc) rather than a 2D projection.

Is this possible with Earth Engine?

I'm unsure whether there's an obvious interface option I'm missing, whether I'd need to do this in the javascript somehow, or if it's simply impossible.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is impossible, but it would be really cool. You should search the developer forum and suggest this if it's not been already.

Comment: something like this http://thematicmapping.org/playground/webgl/earth/?

Comment: I mean yes, it'd be great

Comment: It's possible depending on the constraints of your use case.  Specifically, you can export map tiles and display them in Earth.  [Instructions](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting#exporting-maps).

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to using the [Earth Engine Code Editor](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/playground), the map viewer component is a 2-D interactive map.

However, you can use the Code Editor's [Export.map.toCloudStorage()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#exportmaptocloudstorage) method to produce a set of tiles that can be viewed by Google Earth. See the [Exporting Maps](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting#exporting-maps) section of the Earth Engine docs.

[image]

Here is a [link](https://earth.google.com/web/?kml=https://earth-kml.appspot.com/?link%3Dhttps://storage.googleapis.com/ee-docs-demos/mapToCloudExample/$%255Blevel%255D/$%255Bx%255D/$%255By%255D%26icon%3Dhttps://storage.googleapis.com/earth-kml.appspot.com/no_icon.png%26name%3DmapToCloudExample%26north%3D1.001372066747515%26south%3D-3.004109501935332%26east%3D40.0%26west%3D34.0%26minLevel%3D0%26maxLevel%3D13) to open this example in Google Earth.